# How to Show the Code and design window in dreamwaver

Tags: macromedia

I cant see the design of my code in dreamwaver. i want to switch the code to design. please help me[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEGOQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got to - View, Toolbar (right at the bottom), and select Document from the 
fly out list (assuming it is unticked).

Comment: Thank you so much! .. :)